# Is it possible to make a key word search of all existing channels of all the irc networks from the command line ?

Tags: command-line, irc

I am new to IRC (internet relay chat), as I understand it, 
an IRC network has a unique name like DALnet, is made of a chain of servers, a person can connect to one of them in order to connect to the whole IRC network, one of the servers is not connected to people but to bots of whom each one provides a service like keeping memory of a nickname, another bot provides a service which enables creating channels. There are many of this IRC networks, each has an own name and slightly different rules.

[image]

Now is it possible to go through each channel that exists in all irc networks and search for a certain keyword , like "ancient Chinese ghost stories" or one without spaces?